# .show() and .hide() commands not working correctly

Tags: jquery, html, css, codeigniter

I am currently developing a calendar system with the Codeigniter framework. I want a div to be shown each time a day cell in the calendar template is clicked.

The divs are created by a php for loop and populated from the database in the following view file:

calendar_view.php

```
    <div class="cal_container">

<?php echo $calendar; ?>

<div class="day_expanded_container">

<?php for ($i = 1; $i<=31; $i++):?>

    <div class="day_expanded" id"<?php echo 'd'.$i;?>">

    <?php if (isset($calendar_info[$i])):?>


        <h2><?php echo $calendar_info[$i]['title'];?></h2>

        <p><?php echo $calendar_info[$i]['text']?></p>

    <?php else: ?>

        <h2>No Data for this Date</h2>

        <p>There is currently nothing planned for this Calendar date.</p>

    <?php endif; ?>

    </div>

<?php endfor;?>

</div>

</div>
```

The following jQuery is then applied:

scripts.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var divs = $('div.day_expanded_container > div').get();

    var today = $(".today").attr("id");

    $(divs).hide().filter('#d' + today).show();

    $(".day").click(function() {

        var selected = $(this).attr("id");


        $(divs).hide().filter('#d' + selected).show();


    });

});
```

However on loading the page the divs are all hidden, and clicking does not show at all.

All id's etc are correct and I can't find anything in the css that will over-ride. Is there something glaringly obvious that I am doing wrong ?

Thanks very much

Comment: example code from the client side would be of more help than the php code.

Comment: You have `$(".day").click( ... )`, but I see no elements with the `.day` class.

Comment: I don't understand why you would use `.get()` and then keep passing the array back into the jQuery factory. Also, from what I can tell in reading through your JS, you are creating IDs like `id="1"` somewhere in your calendar. Per http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.2 those are invalid IDs and may be leading to some of your troubles.

Comment: All of my above comments still apply, but the basic idea is working in Safari for me: http://jsfiddle.net/JAAulde/YPPBw/

Comment: The `.today` and `.day` elements appear to be missing from the posted code.  @JAA actually I think the ids are `d1`, `d2`, etc.

Comment: @kingjiv - I don't think you're totally following what's going on here--mostly because not all pertinent markup was given. The OP has elements with numbers as IDs with corresponding elements that have "d{n}" Ids.

Comment: @JAA Ah, the missing `.today` element, I see.  Numbers are allowed in HTML 5, maybe he's on the cutting edge...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing an equals sign:

```
id"<?php echo 'd'.$i;?>"
```

should be

```
id="<?php echo 'd'.$i;?>"
```

Comment: This solved my problem - though I realise I was over complicating the issue which was causing trouble with duplicate and invalid ID's. I want to shoot myself for missing something so fundamental. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

If you have the id of the element you want to hide, you should just address it directly rather than the complicated filter you're using.  For example, if the ID you want to hide is:

```
'#d' + selected
```

then, you should just use this jQuery to hide it:

```
$('#d' + selected).hide();
```

IDs are required to be unique in your page so there is no reason to scope them to some parent and, in fact, a global ID search is probably faster because it can use the native getElementById inside of jQuery which is present in all browsers.

If, for any reason, your IDs are not unique in your page, then that is a problem you have to fix before CSS selector operations on them will work reliably.

Comment: While I understand what you're saying, I don't think this will solve the problem.

Comment: @JAAulde - There may be other problems too (the whole JS code is pretty overly complicated), but this one should be fixed too.

Comment: I appreciate what you mean - I have simplified the system in so far as the filter. As for how else the js is overly complicated I would love to know ? I have to use a hack to get the value for the current Day from the codeigniter calendar I suppose. I'm looking to make this code as proper as I can - so any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: If you can show the generated html, we can help simplify the js code. I don't know php myself so its hard for me to see what the page html actually looks like.